# .vimrc auto add Creation Date, Script Name, Last Updated: inside comments

Tags: vim

This is part of my .vimrc file:

```
set number
filetype plugin indent on
set hidden
set term=builtin_ansi
syntax on
  if has("autocmd")
          augroup content
               autocmd BufNewFile *.pl
                  \ 0put = '#!/usr/bin/perl'  |
                 \ 1put = '' |
                 \ 2put = '# Script Name:' |
                 \ 3put = '# Written by: Michael H. Roberts' |
                 \ 4put = '# Creation Date: ' |
                 \ 5put = '# Last Edited: ' |
                 \ 6put = 'use warnings;' |
                 \ 7put = 'use diagnostics;' |
                 \ norm gg10jf]
              augroup END
  endif
```

This is so my *.pl files automatically open with the above comments. I would really like the files to open with the name of the file, creation date and last edited information added by the .vimrc file. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be aware that there are several ready-made template and snippet plugins on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/); you just need to search and evaluate them. A little home-grown solution is fine, but it's important to realize when building upon it becomes a wasted effort in duplication.

That said, since you're already using `:put` with the expression register (`=`), adding dynamic elements is just a matter of appending (`"text" . "more text" . funccall()`) the results of function calls; please refer to the corresponding `:help` for more information on the built-in functions:

- name of the file → `expand('%:t')`
- creation date → `strftime()`
- last edited information → probably derived from a version control system, via external command `system('git ...')`

Comment: Thank you, I was omitting the .

Comment: Yes, this is a bit unusual (`+` and `&` are more common). If this answers your question, please mark it by pressing the outlined checkmark next to it.